# $B(T)$ and $B^a(T^a)$ are same distribution? ($T$ and $T^a$ are same distribution)

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $\{B_1(t):t\geq0\}$ be a one dimensional Brownian motion. Then, $\{B^a_1(t):t\geq0\}$ is also a Brownian motion where $B^a_1(t):=a^{-1}B_1(a^2t)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\{B_2(t):t\geq0\}$ be a one dimensional Brownian motion independent of $\{B_1(t):t\geq0\}$.
For $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $T:=\inf\{t\geq0:B_2(t)=b\}$ and $T^a:=\inf\{t\geq0:B^a_2(t)=b\}$ have same distribution where $B^a_2(t):=a^{-1}B_2(a^2t)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

I already know these facts is right.

**Question**

> $B_1(T)$ and $B^a_1(T^a)$ have same distribution?

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B^a(T^a)=B(T)=b$ by definition of your stopping time (note that $T$ and $T^a$ are a.s. finite), so yes.

Comment: thank you for answer. sorry, my question was mistaken.

Comment: The answer to your new question is yes because $(B_1, B_2, T)$ has the same distribution as $(B_1^a,B_2^a, T^a)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know much. Well, to prove $B_1(T),B^a_1(T^a)$ have the same distribution, should I show $P(B^a_1(T^a)\in A)=P(B_1(T)\in A)$ ? This follows what you said ?

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself with the various realisations of the Brownian Motion you've created. You're really looking at the measurable space $X=C([0,\infty))\times C([0,\infty))\times [0,\infty)$ and the measurable map $(f,g,t)\mapsto f(t)$. So what's your measure on $X$? It's $W\otimes (W,\tau_b)$ where $W$ denotes the Brownian Motion measure and $(W,\tau_b)$ is the joint distribution of a Brownian Motion and its first hitting time of $b$. But that's the case whether or not you've added superscript $a$.

Comment: Once the measure on $X$ are the same, then the push-forward measure under the above map (i.e., the distribution of $f(t)$) is the same - this is immediate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I was very confused. Now, I get it thanks to your accurate comment !